# Как проверить файл на существование?

Tags: php, файлы

Пробую проверить файл на существование. Адрес файла идёт по `url`, а не через корневой каталог. К примеру, файл:

http://name.ru/чукча.jpg

```
if (@fopen("http://name.ru/чукча.jpg", "r")){
 echo "чукча есть..";
} else {
 echo "чукчи нет..";
}
```

Как можно проверить файл на наличие, если в нём присутствуют кириллические символы?

Comment: А так же, как и если бы имя файла в латинице не получается?

Comment: Да собственно пробовал... но что-то не пропускает :(

Answer (score 2):

```
if(is_file('http://name.ru/чукча.jpg')){
    echo "чукча есть..";
} else {
    echo "чукчи нет..";
}
```

> is_file() - Возвращает TRUE, если файл
> существует и является обычным файлом,
> иначе возвращает FALSE.

Comment: Всё время почему-то думал что is_file() не работает с URL...

Comment: @Oll, не во всех версиях php - так будет точнее.> Начиная с PHP 5.0.0, эта функция также> может быть использована с некоторыми> обертками url. Список оберток,> поддерживаемых семейством функций> stat(), смотрите в Поддерживаемые> протоколы и обработчики (wrappers).[Подробнее о is_file()](http://www.php.ru/manual/function.is-file.html)В конце концов, можете использовать следующий способ:    if(@file_get_contents('http://name.ru/чукча.jpg')){        echo "чукча есть..";    } else {        echo "чукчи нет..";    }

Answer (score -1):

Проверьте размеры файла (ширину, высоту). Если вернёт не "0", значит существует.

Comment: А разме getimagesize - не вернёт ошибку в случае если файл не будет найден... Но всёравно попробую...